# how I can use a rest template in springboot to save new Object

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, spring-boot

I have tow applications students and actions with tow ports `8080` and `8081`. In the first app I have a table and I have a method of save student. But the problem is how to sent from this method , this saved object to other app and saving it in the table of the second app. Are there rests between more than one app ?

The method in the first app :

```
saveStudent() ... StudentDao.save();
```

The method in the secont app :

```
save Income() ...
```

Answer (score 1):

**First app:**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/firstApp")
public class FirstAppController{

 @Autowired
 private StudentRepository studentRepository;

 private RestTemplate restTemplate =new RestTemplate();

@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<String> save(@RequestBody Student student){
  Student savedStudent = studentRepository.saveAndFlush(student);
  //set your headers
  HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
  headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

  //set your entity to send
  HttpEntity entity = new HttpEntity(savedStudent ,headers);
  // send it!
  return restTemplate.exchange("http://localhost:8081/secondeApp", HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class);
 }

}
```

The access url of the first service : **[POST]:** `http;//localhost:8080/firstApp`

**Second app:**

```
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/secondeApp")
    public class SecondeAppController{

     @Autowired
     private StudentRepository studentRepository;

    @PostMapping(consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public void save(@RequestBody Student student){
      studentRepository.saveAndFlush(student);
     }

    }
```

Comment: thank u . in the controller of the first app i have the post method ( saveStudent ) and in the serviceImpl i want to send the new object with params to the second app to the post method in it and save it in the new table after thai i save it in the first table  ...